Calculating partial derivatives of parallel transport
Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and let $\nabla$ a linear connection on $M$ (not necessarily the Levi-Civita connection). Let $x,y\in M$ and denote $\gamma(t)$ the minimal geodesic connecting such points. I am interested in computing the partial derivatives $\partial_{y^k}$ of the components of the parallel transport map (matrix) $\Gamma_{y,x}:T_xM\to T_yM$ along $\gamma$. Of course solving the parallel transport equation in such abstract setting and then computing the derivatives doesn't look very promising, so I am wondering if there is a "smart" way of approaching this calculation. I would expect some relation with the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ of the connection. If assuming $\nabla$ to be the Levi-Civita connections simplifies the calculation, there is no problem.
Thanks for any suggestion.
